# Haskell - Fungen Framework - Rendering problem

Tags: haskell

I'm starting to use Fungen library for Haskell to make some games, but I've a problem with rendering. When I compile and run some code, it shows me the images and everything working, but at every game cycle, some black stripes appear. A friend of mine installed the same tool and things but he doesn't have that rendering problem, using the same code i wrote!.

Does anybody know how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: As you describe it, it seems that the problem lies in your machine's configuration or libraries. Some context (OS, distro if appliable, architecture, hardware, etc.) may be helpful.

Comment: I'm using Windows XP, and my pc isn't that slow, I have an AMD dual core processor and 2GB of RAM. My hardware is similar to my friends one, but he is using Windows 7. I hope it helps.

If someone had the same problem it may be much easier to understand xD

Comment: Are you using double-buffering? This kind of "black stripe" thing reminds me a lot of the kinds of artefacts I used to see when I didn't know about that technique -- and they're very finicky. Slight changes in monitor refresh rate, CPU speed, or weather can make them disappear (or make them ten times worse). Then again, most graphics library do double-buffering by default these days...

Comment: I tried changing monitor refresh rate from 60, to 70, 72 and 85, but nothing changed. I've looked for some code, to see how to change double buffering, but I couldn't find examples that I understand. This is the only one I found, but I didn't understand how to use it: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Opengl#Animations_flicker. If someone understands more about glut double buffering or OpenGl double buffering in haskell and wants to help, I'll be pleased :D. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: I think I solved the problem! I found that the problem was that I NEEDED to use double buffering, but By default it's turned off! I Think that my friends default configuration is Double Buffering, so that's why it didn't worked in my PC. I downloaded de funInit source code from fugen, added the double buffing and used that code now, and it works! Thanks Daniel Wagner for the answer, it made me look for a lot of hours but at last I found it, Thank you all!

Comment: Do you have a solution? I have a similar problem? Where do you turn on double buffering in FunGEn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can easily initialize a Haskell FunGEn program to double buffer by saying:

```
import Graphics.UI.GLUT
```

and then prior to creating your window stating:

```
 initialDisplayMode $= [DoubleBuffered]
```